# Trouble in RSpec test - saving parent record twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rspec, nested-attributes

I'm new at Rails programming, and my RSpec test is failing when trying to save nested records. The logs from the test suggest that ActiveRecord is trying to save the parent twice, which results in a silent database save failure.

**sign_up_spec.rb** (sorry for the omission!)

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Accounts", type: :feature do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  scenario "creating an account" do
    visit root_path
    click_link "Sign Up"
    fill_in "Account name", :with => "Test Firm"
    fill_in "Username", :with => user.username
    fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
    fill_in "Password confirmation", :with => user.password_confirmation
    click_button "Create Account"
    success_message = "Your account has been successfully created."
    expect(page).to have_content(success_message)
    expect(page).to have_content("Signed in as #{user.username}")
  end
end
```

**account.rb**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 8, maximum: 20 }
end
```

**account_controller.rb**

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @account = Account.new
    @account.build_owner
  end

  def create
    account = Account.create(account_params)
    env["warden"].set_user(account.owner, :scope => :user)
    env["warden"].set_user(account, :scope => :account)
    flash[:success] = "Your account has been successfully created."
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

    def account_params
     params.require(:account).permit(:account_name, {:owner_attributes => [
        :username, :password, :password_confirmation
        ]})
    end
end
```

**account new.html.erb**

```
<h2>Sign Up</h2>
<%= form_for(@account) do |account| %>
  <p>
    <%= account.label :account_name %><br>
    <%= account.text_field :account_name %>
  </p>
  <%= account.fields_for :owner do |owner| %>
    <p>
      <%= owner.label :username %><br>
      <%= owner.text_field :username %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= owner.label :password %><br>
      <%= owner.password_field :password %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= owner.label :password_confirmation %><br>
      <%= owner.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
  <%= account.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The following excerpt from the test result log below suggests that ActiveRecord is trying to insert the User record twice, once during the Account#new function, and again in the Account#create function. I've added comments with my understanding of what's going on through the process:

**test log**

```
Started GET "/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-17 15:50:43 +0000
Processing by AccountsController#new as HTML
Rendered accounts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (45.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 110ms (Views: 51.6ms | ActiveRecord: 6.9ms)

# it appears that this action is happening from the Account#new method;
# why would @account.build_owner cause a database action?
(0.4ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
User Exists (30.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('user1') LIMIT 1
SQL (3.8ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("username", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["username", "user1"], ["password_digest", "blahblah"], ["created_at", "2015-06-17 13:15:40.667965"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-17 13:15:40.667965"]]
(1.4ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Started POST "/accounts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-17 13:15:40 +0000
Processing by AccountsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "account"=>{"account_name"=>"Test Firm", "owner_attributes"=>{"username"=>"user1", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}, "commit"=>"Create Account"}

# the Account#create function wants to add the user a second time (or more
# accurately, the first time), but the user parent already exists from above
# so it fails the uniqueness test
(0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
User Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('user1') LIMIT 1

# which causes the query to bomb
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1

#and neither the parent or child records are created
#<Account id: nil, account_name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, owner_id: nil>
#<User id: nil, username: "user1", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "blahblah">
Redirected to http://www.example.com/
Completed 302 Found in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-17 13:15:40 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 5.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
(4.3ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the rspec test that is causing the issue

Comment: @infused agreed, I'm suspicious of the test code because the record is being saved to the database AFTER the `get` request is completed, but BEFORE the `post` request starts, indicating that something in the test code is manually creating the instance. Also, you're passing the symbol version of `owner` in the nested form, which means Rails is going to build a new instance of `owner` and then assign it to the `@account`. You already, however, built an instance of `owner` for `@account` inside the `new` action. So that code is redundant.

Comment: hi and welcome to stack overflow. In order for us to help you debug your *spec*, you need to actually include your *spec*  in your question. Please edit your question and add the relevant spec file. (don't put code in the comments because formatting it awful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in `sign_up_spec.rb`. Your test has a `let` for `user`, which means the first time you mention `user` in your tests it will create a `user`. However, your application code is supposed to create the user itself.

As I said in the comment, this is why in your test log you see that it successfully completes the `get` request and then, *before* the `post` request, the `user` gets created. When your code tries to create a `user` after submitting the form, it's already been created!

I commented your test spec to make this more clear:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
scenario "creating an account" do
    visit root_path
    click_link "Sign Up" # this is the successful get request
    fill_in "Account name", :with => "Test Firm"
    fill_in "Username", :with => user.username # this triggers the let and creates a user
    fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
    fill_in "Password confirmation", :with => user.password_confirmation
    click_button "Create Account" # this starts the post request
    success_message = "Your account has been successfully created."
    expect(page).to have_content(success_message)
    expect(page).to have_content("Signed in as #{user.username}")
end
```

To fix this, just change the `let` statement to use FactoryGirl's `attributes_for` method instead and use `with: user[:username]` instead of `with: user.username`.

Also, you're passing the symbol version of `owner` in the nested form, which means Rails is going to build a new instance of `owner` and then assign it to the `@account`. You already, however, built an instance of `owner` for `@account` inside the `new` action. So that code is redundant. Either remove the `build_owner` line from the controller action, or pass `@account.owner` to the `fields_for` call in your view.